# Getting Screen Positions of D3 Nodes After Transform

Tags: d3.js, position, zooming, transform

I'm trying to get the screen position of a node after the layout has been transformed by d3.behavior.zoom() but I'm not having much luck. How might I go about getting a node's actual position in the window after translating and scaling the layout?

```
mouseOver = function(node) {
  screenX = magic(node.x); // Need a magic function to transform node
  screenY = magic(node.y); // positions into screen coordinates.
};
```

Any guidance would be appreciated.

EDIT: 'node' above is a force layout node, so it's x and y properties are set by the simulation and remain constant after the simulation comes to rest, regardless of what type of transform is applied.

EDIT: The strategy I'm using to transform the SVG comes from d3's zoom behavior, which is outlined here: [SVG Geometric Zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999).

```
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
    .call(d3.behavior.zoom().scaleExtent([1, 8]).on("zoom", zoom))
  .append("g");

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("class", "overlay")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 2.5)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });

function zoom() {
  svg.attr("transform", "translate(" + d3.event.translate + ")scale(" + d3.event.scale + ")");
}
```

It's pretty straightforward. d3's zoom behavior delivers pan and zoom events to a handler, which applies the transforms to the container element by way of the transform attribute.

EDIT: I'm working around the issue by using mouse coordinates instead of node coordinates, since I'm interested in the node position when the node is hovered over with the mouse pointer. It's not exactly the behavior I'm after, but it works for the most part, and is better than nothing.

EDIT: The solution was to get the current transformation matrix of the svg element with element.getCTM() and then use it to offset the x and y coordinates to a screen-relative state. See below.

Comment: I suspect the answer might involve doing something with getCTM() and/or getScreenCTM() of the SVG element [Basic Data Types](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getCTM). I'm wondering if there are helper methods to operate on the matrices returned by those functions, such as Inverse(tm) or something to that effect.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try `node.getBBox()` to get the pixel positions of a tight bounding box around the node shapes after any `transform` has been applied.  See here for more: [link](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#__svg__SVGLocatable__getBBox).

EDIT:

`getBBox` doesn't work quite the way I thought. Since the rectangle is defined in terms of the transformed coordinate space it is always relative to the parent `<g>` and will therefore always be the same for contained shapes.

There is another function called [element.getBoundingClientRect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/element.getBoundingClientRect) that appears to be quite widely supported and it returns its rectangle in pixel position relative to the top left of the browser view port.  That might get you closer to what you want without needing to mess with the transform matrix directly.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The doc definitely says that getBBox() is post transform, but I'm getting the same coordinates for node.x and node.y as I do for el.getBBox().x and el.getBBox().y. Just to note, 'node' is a force layout node which is part of the selection's data.

Comment: What is the transform that is applied to the element at the time getBBox is called?

Comment: I edited my post in an attempt to answer your question. I'm applying translate and scale transforms via the container's transform attribute. [SVG Geometric Zooming](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3680999)

Comment: If you look in the Elements tab of the Chrome dev tools, what is the actual value of the transform attribute on the element?  Does it make sense with what getBBox is telling you?

Comment: The transform is actually being applied to the parent 'svg:g' element. However inspecting cx and cy for the svg node show that those values don't change when the layout is transformed, and those values are consistent with the values returned by getBBox().

Comment: Since you're transforming the <g> I don't expect cx and cy would ever change (they will always be relative to the transformation applied to the <g>). But I don't understand why getBBox isn't returning the true post-transform coordinate.  What browser are you on?  Out of curiousity, can you set up a jsfiddle that shows this?

Comment: I'm on Chrome/OSX 10.7.5. I was able to develop a decent solution, shown in an answer below. If I can find time to set up a jsfiddle I will. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I just double checked and getBBox() is definitely unaffected by scale and translation. **SVGRect {height: 50, width: 50, y: 231.6396484375, x: 547.475341796875}** That value is returned on a specific node regardless of how I've panned and zoomed. I suspect it might be because the transform is being applied to the parent container and not the specific node, but I can't say for sure.

Comment: You can see the behavior here: [Force Editor](http://bl.ocks.org/benzguo/raw/4370043/3b385a7336a11c97da0871a3dd57f2311b8864bd/). You can see the transforms applied to the <g> element in the elements tab. Go to the console and type **d3.select('circle')[0][0].getBBox()**. Do some panning and zooming  and issue the command again. I expect you'll see that the values remain the same.

Comment: It looks like getBBox returns the bounding box in terms of the transformed coordinates. Basically, the box will be relative to the container "g", which is why it's always the same. I actually came across a function that is not part of the SVG standard but seems widely supported and appears to do the right thing.  I'll update the answer with that.

Answer (score 26):

It appears the solution to my original question looks something like this:

(Updated to support rotation transforms.)

```
// The magic function.
function getScreenCoords(x, y, ctm) {
    var xn = ctm.e + x*ctm.a + y*ctm.c;
    var yn = ctm.f + x*ctm.b + y*ctm.d;
    return { x: xn, y: yn };
}

var circle = document.getElementById('svgCircle'),
cx = +circle.getAttribute('cx'),
cy = +circle.getAttribute('cy'),
ctm = circle.getCTM(),
coords = getScreenCoords(cx, cy, ctm);
console.log(coords.x, coords.y); // shows coords relative to my svg container
```

Alternately, this can also be done using the translate and scale properties from d3.event (if rotation transforms are not needed):

```
// This function is called by d3's zoom event.
function zoom() {

// The magic function - converts node positions into positions on screen.    
function getScreenCoords(x, y, translate, scale) {
    var xn = translate[0] + x*scale;
    var yn = translate[1] + y*scale;
    return { x: xn, y: yn };
}

// Get element coordinates and transform them to screen coordinates.
var circle = document.getElementById('svgCircle');
cx = +circle.getAttribute('cx'),
cy = +circle.getAttribute('cy'),
coords = getScreenCoords(cx, cy, d3.event.translate, d3.event.scale);
console.log(coords.x, coords.y); // shows coords relative to my svg container

  // ...
}
```

EDIT: I found the below form of the function to be the most useful and generic, and it seems to stand up where `getBoundingClientRect` falls down. More specifically, when I was trying to get accurate SVG node positions in a D3 force layout project, `getBoundingClientRect` produced inaccurate results while the below method returned the `circle` element's exact center coordinates across multiple browsers.

(Updated to support rotation transforms.)

```
// Pass in the element and its pre-transform coords
function getElementCoords(element, coords) {
    var ctm = element.getCTM(),
    x = ctm.e + coords.x*ctm.a + coords.y*ctm.c,
    y = ctm.f + coords.x*ctm.b + coords.y*ctm.d;
    return {x: x, y: y};
};

// Get post-transform coords from the element.
var circle = document.getElementById('svgCircle'),
x = +circle.getAttribute('cx'),
y = +circle.getAttribute('cy'),
coords = getElementCoords(circle, {x:x, y:y});

// Get post-transform coords using a 'node' object.
// Any object with x,y properties will do.
var node = ..., // some D3 node or object with x,y properties.
circle = document.getElementById('svgCircle'),
coords = getElementCoords(circle, node);
```

The function works by getting the transform matrix of the DOM element, and then using the matrix rotation, scale, and translate information to return the post-transform coordinates of the given node object.

Comment: Thank you so much this made my day, i was searching the internet for hours for a solution.

Comment: Hum, Could you confirm, this function still doesn't work when rotations are applied right ? Because you are not using ctm.b and ctm.c to transform the coordinates.

Comment: Anyone know how to apply the rotation transforms to the getElementCoords() function?

Comment: @poliu2s, if memory serves you'll need to `xn = ctm.e + coords.x*ctm.a + coords.y*ctm.b` and `yn = ctm.f + coords.x*ctm.c + coords.y*ctm.d`. If that works let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: @poliu2s, it looks like I have the rotation elements reversed in the previous comment. This should work: `x = ctm.e + coords.x*ctm.a + coords.y*ctm.c` and `y = ctm.f + coords.x*ctm.b + coords.y*ctm.d`.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code for rotation transforms. Worked.