# How to get coordinates of an svg element?

Tags: javascript, dom, svg, d3.js

I am using d3 to draw a line from a relative svg position and hence want to access the coordinates of the element itself. I tried something like this (where "this" refers to the element)

```
 .attr("x1", this.x)
 .attr("y1", this.y)
```

but the x1 and y1 just defaults to zero. What is the correct way to get the coordinates of the svg element?

EDIT:

Here's my (by request) my whole code. I'm trying to implement this on the collapsible tree, where I draw a line when I hover with the mouse over a circle node. The starting point of the line should be from the circle I click on and the ending point should be a fixed point on the svg plane.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.v3.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="d3.layout.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">

.node circle {
  cursor: pointer;
  fill: #fff;
  stroke: steelblue;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

.node text {
  font: 10px sans-serif;
}

path.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #ccc;
  stroke-width: 1.5px;
}

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="chart"></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">

var m = [20, 120, 20, 120],
    w = 2240 - m[1] - m[3],
    h = 800 - m[0] - m[2],
    i = 0,
    duration = 500,
    root;

var tree = d3.layout.tree()
    .size([h, w]);

var diagonal = d3.svg.diagonal()
    .projection(function(d) { return [d.y, d.x]; });

var vis = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", w + m[1] + m[3])
    .attr("height", h + m[0] + m[2])
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + m[3] + "," + m[0] + ")");

function loadData(json) {
    root = json;
    d3.select("#processName").html(root.text);
    root.x0 = h / 2;
    root.y0 = 0;
    root.children.forEach(collapse);
    update(root);  
}

function collapse(d) {
    if (d.children) {
      d._children = d.children;
      d._children.forEach(collapse);
      d.children = null;
    }
 };

// Toggle children on click.
function click(d) {
  if (d.children) {
    d._children = d.children;
    d.children = null;
  } else {
    d.children = d._children;
    d._children = null;
  }
  update(d);
}

function update(source) {

  // Compute the new tree layout.
  var nodes = tree.nodes(root).reverse();

  // Normalize for fixed-depth.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) { d.y = d.depth * 180; });

  // Update the nodes…
  var node = vis.selectAll("g.node")
      .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y0 + "," + source.x0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  nodeEnter.append("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; })
    .on('mouseover', function(d, i){
        var dataset = [1,2,3,4]                                    // HERE
        vis.selectAll("line")                                      // HERE
            .data(dataset)                                 // HERE
            .enter()                                       // HERE
            .append("line")                                // HERE
            .attr("x1", this.x)                            // HERE'S THE PROBLEM FOR PERRY
            .attr("y1", this.y)                            // HERE'S THE PROBLEM FOR PERRY
            .attr("x2", 500)                               // HERE
            .attr("y2", 500)                               // HERE
            .style("stroke", "rgb(6,120,155)");}           // HERE
       ); 

  nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Transition nodes to their new position.
  var nodeUpdate = node.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.y + "," + d.x + ")"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 4.5)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#fff"; });

  nodeUpdate.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  var nodeExit = node.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.y + "," + source.x + ")"; })
      .remove();

  nodeExit.select("circle")
      .attr("r", 1e-6);

  nodeExit.select("text")
      .style("fill-opacity", 1e-6);

  // Update the links…
  var link = vis.selectAll("path.link")
      .data(tree.links(nodes), function(d) { return d.target.id; });

  // Enter any new links at the parent's previous position.
  link.enter().insert("path", "g")
      .attr("class", "link")
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x0, y: source.y0};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
    .transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition links to their new position.
  link.transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", diagonal);

  // Transition exiting nodes to the parent's new position.
  link.exit().transition()
      .duration(duration)
      .attr("d", function(d) {
        var o = {x: source.x, y: source.y};
        return diagonal({source: o, target: o});
      })
      .remove();

  // Stash the old positions for transition.
  nodes.forEach(function(d) {
    d.x0 = d.x;
    d.y0 = d.y;
  });

};

loadData({
 "name": "flare",
 "children": [
  {
   "name": "analytics",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "cluster",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
      {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
      {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
      {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "graph",
     "children": [
      {"name": "BetweennessCentrality", "size": 3534},
      {"name": "LinkDistance", "size": 5731},
      {"name": "MaxFlowMinCut", "size": 7840},
      {"name": "ShortestPaths", "size": 5914},
      {"name": "SpanningTree", "size": 3416}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "optimization",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AspectRatioBanker", "size": 7074}
     ]
    }
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "animate",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Easing", "size": 17010},
    {"name": "FunctionSequence", "size": 5842},
    {
     "name": "interpolate",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ArrayInterpolator", "size": 1983},
      {"name": "ColorInterpolator", "size": 2047},
      {"name": "DateInterpolator", "size": 1375},
      {"name": "Interpolator", "size": 8746},
      {"name": "MatrixInterpolator", "size": 2202},
      {"name": "NumberInterpolator", "size": 1382},
      {"name": "ObjectInterpolator", "size": 1629},
      {"name": "PointInterpolator", "size": 1675},
      {"name": "RectangleInterpolator", "size": 2042}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "ISchedulable", "size": 1041},
    {"name": "Parallel", "size": 5176},
    {"name": "Pause", "size": 449},
    {"name": "Scheduler", "size": 5593},
    {"name": "Sequence", "size": 5534},
    {"name": "Transition", "size": 9201},
    {"name": "Transitioner", "size": 19975},
    {"name": "TransitionEvent", "size": 1116},
    {"name": "Tween", "size": 6006}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "data",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "converters",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Converters", "size": 721},
      {"name": "DelimitedTextConverter", "size": 4294},
      {"name": "GraphMLConverter", "size": 9800},
      {"name": "IDataConverter", "size": 1314},
      {"name": "JSONConverter", "size": 2220}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "DataField", "size": 1759},
    {"name": "DataSchema", "size": 2165},
    {"name": "DataSet", "size": 586},
    {"name": "DataSource", "size": 3331},
    {"name": "DataTable", "size": 772},
    {"name": "DataUtil", "size": 3322}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "display",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DirtySprite", "size": 8833},
    {"name": "LineSprite", "size": 1732},
    {"name": "RectSprite", "size": 3623},
    {"name": "TextSprite", "size": 10066}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "flex",
   "children": [
    {"name": "FlareVis", "size": 4116}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "physics",
   "children": [
    {"name": "DragForce", "size": 1082},
    {"name": "GravityForce", "size": 1336},
    {"name": "IForce", "size": 319},
    {"name": "NBodyForce", "size": 10498},
    {"name": "Particle", "size": 2822},
    {"name": "Simulation", "size": 9983},
    {"name": "Spring", "size": 2213},
    {"name": "SpringForce", "size": 1681}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "query",
   "children": [
    {"name": "AggregateExpression", "size": 1616},
    {"name": "And", "size": 1027},
    {"name": "Arithmetic", "size": 3891},
    {"name": "Average", "size": 891},
    {"name": "BinaryExpression", "size": 2893},
    {"name": "Comparison", "size": 5103},
    {"name": "CompositeExpression", "size": 3677},
    {"name": "Count", "size": 781},
    {"name": "DateUtil", "size": 4141},
    {"name": "Distinct", "size": 933},
    {"name": "Expression", "size": 5130},
    {"name": "ExpressionIterator", "size": 3617},
    {"name": "Fn", "size": 3240},
    {"name": "If", "size": 2732},
    {"name": "IsA", "size": 2039},
    {"name": "Literal", "size": 1214},
    {"name": "Match", "size": 3748},
    {"name": "Maximum", "size": 843},
    {
     "name": "methods",
     "children": [
      {"name": "add", "size": 593},
      {"name": "and", "size": 330},
      {"name": "average", "size": 287},
      {"name": "count", "size": 277},
      {"name": "distinct", "size": 292},
      {"name": "div", "size": 595},
      {"name": "eq", "size": 594},
      {"name": "fn", "size": 460},
      {"name": "gt", "size": 603},
      {"name": "gte", "size": 625},
      {"name": "iff", "size": 748},
      {"name": "isa", "size": 461},
      {"name": "lt", "size": 597},
      {"name": "lte", "size": 619},
      {"name": "max", "size": 283},
      {"name": "min", "size": 283},
      {"name": "mod", "size": 591},
      {"name": "mul", "size": 603},
      {"name": "neq", "size": 599},
      {"name": "not", "size": 386},
      {"name": "or", "size": 323},
      {"name": "orderby", "size": 307},
      {"name": "range", "size": 772},
      {"name": "select", "size": 296},
      {"name": "stddev", "size": 363},
      {"name": "sub", "size": 600},
      {"name": "sum", "size": 280},
      {"name": "update", "size": 307},
      {"name": "variance", "size": 335},
      {"name": "where", "size": 299},
      {"name": "xor", "size": 354},
      {"name": "_", "size": 264}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Minimum", "size": 843},
    {"name": "Not", "size": 1554},
    {"name": "Or", "size": 970},
    {"name": "Query", "size": 13896},
    {"name": "Range", "size": 1594},
    {"name": "StringUtil", "size": 4130},
    {"name": "Sum", "size": 791},
    {"name": "Variable", "size": 1124},
    {"name": "Variance", "size": 1876},
    {"name": "Xor", "size": 1101}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "scale",
   "children": [
    {"name": "IScaleMap", "size": 2105},
    {"name": "LinearScale", "size": 1316},
    {"name": "LogScale", "size": 3151},
    {"name": "OrdinalScale", "size": 3770},
    {"name": "QuantileScale", "size": 2435},
    {"name": "QuantitativeScale", "size": 4839},
    {"name": "RootScale", "size": 1756},
    {"name": "Scale", "size": 4268},
    {"name": "ScaleType", "size": 1821},
    {"name": "TimeScale", "size": 5833}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "util",
   "children": [
    {"name": "Arrays", "size": 8258},
    {"name": "Colors", "size": 10001},
    {"name": "Dates", "size": 8217},
    {"name": "Displays", "size": 12555},
    {"name": "Filter", "size": 2324},
    {"name": "Geometry", "size": 10993},
    {
     "name": "heap",
     "children": [
      {"name": "FibonacciHeap", "size": 9354},
      {"name": "HeapNode", "size": 1233}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "IEvaluable", "size": 335},
    {"name": "IPredicate", "size": 383},
    {"name": "IValueProxy", "size": 874},
    {
     "name": "math",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DenseMatrix", "size": 3165},
      {"name": "IMatrix", "size": 2815},
      {"name": "SparseMatrix", "size": 3366}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Maths", "size": 17705},
    {"name": "Orientation", "size": 1486},
    {
     "name": "palette",
     "children": [
      {"name": "ColorPalette", "size": 6367},
      {"name": "Palette", "size": 1229},
      {"name": "ShapePalette", "size": 2059},
      {"name": "SizePalette", "size": 2291}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Property", "size": 5559},
    {"name": "Shapes", "size": 19118},
    {"name": "Sort", "size": 6887},
    {"name": "Stats", "size": 6557},
    {"name": "Strings", "size": 22026}
   ]
  },
  {
   "name": "vis",
   "children": [
    {
     "name": "axis",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Axes", "size": 1302},
      {"name": "Axis", "size": 24593},
      {"name": "AxisGridLine", "size": 652},
      {"name": "AxisLabel", "size": 636},
      {"name": "CartesianAxes", "size": 6703}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "controls",
     "children": [
      {"name": "AnchorControl", "size": 2138},
      {"name": "ClickControl", "size": 3824},
      {"name": "Control", "size": 1353},
      {"name": "ControlList", "size": 4665},
      {"name": "DragControl", "size": 2649},
      {"name": "ExpandControl", "size": 2832},
      {"name": "HoverControl", "size": 4896},
      {"name": "IControl", "size": 763},
      {"name": "PanZoomControl", "size": 5222},
      {"name": "SelectionControl", "size": 7862},
      {"name": "TooltipControl", "size": 8435}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "data",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Data", "size": 20544},
      {"name": "DataList", "size": 19788},
      {"name": "DataSprite", "size": 10349},
      {"name": "EdgeSprite", "size": 3301},
      {"name": "NodeSprite", "size": 19382},
      {
       "name": "render",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ArrowType", "size": 698},
        {"name": "EdgeRenderer", "size": 5569},
        {"name": "IRenderer", "size": 353},
        {"name": "ShapeRenderer", "size": 2247}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "ScaleBinding", "size": 11275},
      {"name": "Tree", "size": 7147},
      {"name": "TreeBuilder", "size": 9930}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "events",
     "children": [
      {"name": "DataEvent", "size": 2313},
      {"name": "SelectionEvent", "size": 1880},
      {"name": "TooltipEvent", "size": 1701},
      {"name": "VisualizationEvent", "size": 1117}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "legend",
     "children": [
      {"name": "Legend", "size": 20859},
      {"name": "LegendItem", "size": 4614},
      {"name": "LegendRange", "size": 10530}
     ]
    },
    {
     "name": "operator",
     "children": [
      {
       "name": "distortion",
       "children": [
        {"name": "BifocalDistortion", "size": 4461},
        {"name": "Distortion", "size": 6314},
        {"name": "FisheyeDistortion", "size": 3444}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "encoder",
       "children": [
        {"name": "ColorEncoder", "size": 3179},
        {"name": "Encoder", "size": 4060},
        {"name": "PropertyEncoder", "size": 4138},
        {"name": "ShapeEncoder", "size": 1690},
        {"name": "SizeEncoder", "size": 1830}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "filter",
       "children": [
        {"name": "FisheyeTreeFilter", "size": 5219},
        {"name": "GraphDistanceFilter", "size": 3165},
        {"name": "VisibilityFilter", "size": 3509}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "IOperator", "size": 1286},
      {
       "name": "label",
       "children": [
        {"name": "Labeler", "size": 9956},
        {"name": "RadialLabeler", "size": 3899},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLabeler", "size": 3202}
       ]
      },
      {
       "name": "layout",
       "children": [
        {"name": "AxisLayout", "size": 6725},
        {"name": "BundledEdgeRouter", "size": 3727},
        {"name": "CircleLayout", "size": 9317},
        {"name": "CirclePackingLayout", "size": 12003},
        {"name": "DendrogramLayout", "size": 4853},
        {"name": "ForceDirectedLayout", "size": 8411},
        {"name": "IcicleTreeLayout", "size": 4864},
        {"name": "IndentedTreeLayout", "size": 3174},
        {"name": "Layout", "size": 7881},
        {"name": "NodeLinkTreeLayout", "size": 12870},
        {"name": "PieLayout", "size": 2728},
        {"name": "RadialTreeLayout", "size": 12348},
        {"name": "RandomLayout", "size": 870},
        {"name": "StackedAreaLayout", "size": 9121},
        {"name": "TreeMapLayout", "size": 9191}
       ]
      },
      {"name": "Operator", "size": 2490},
      {"name": "OperatorList", "size": 5248},
      {"name": "OperatorSequence", "size": 4190},
      {"name": "OperatorSwitch", "size": 2581},
      {"name": "SortOperator", "size": 2023}
     ]
    },
    {"name": "Visualization", "size": 16540}
   ]
  }
 ]
});


    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The way to determine the coordinates depends on what element you're working with. For `circle`s for example, the `cx` and `cy` attributes determine the center position. In addition, you may have a `translation` applied through the `transform` attribute which changes the reference point of any coordinates.

Most of the ways used in general to get screen coordinates won't work for SVGs. In addition, you may not want absolute coordinates if the line you want to draw is in the same container as the elements it connects.

Edit:

In your particular code, it's quite difficult to get the position of the node because its determined by a translation of the parent element. So you need to get the transform attribute of the parent node and extract the translation from that.

```
d3.transform(d3.select(this.parentNode).attr("transform")).translate
```

Working jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k8Edq/).

Comment: I happen to be working with circles so I changed the coordinates to .attr("x1", this.cx) and .attr("x1", this.cy) but still defaults to  zero. How can it do that if the coordinates of a circle is cx and cy? Am I totally misunderstanding something? (would be possible, because I haven't jumped over the steep learning curve that d3 has :P)

Comment: Depends entirely on what `this` is. Have you tried `d3.select(this).attr("cx")`?

Comment: `this` is the circle I am working with. I also tried `d3.select(this).attr("cx")` but still defaults to zero.

Comment: Couldn't upload it on jsfiddle for some reason so included the whole code in my question (should be easy to copy since I include the json in the code). I also highlight where exactly the problem is.

Comment: If what's needed is the actual element position relative to its container, element.getBoundingClientRect() should do the trick. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554224/getting-screen-positions-of-d3-nodes-after-transform

Comment: I get an error in d3 v4, stating that transform is not a function (the example jsfiddle above is in v3). [this is not a criticism, the answer is correct for v3]

Answer (score 76):

The [`element.getBoundingClientRect()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect) method will return the proper coordinates of an element relative to the viewport regardless of whether the svg has been scaled and/or translated.

[See this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554224/getting-screen-positions-of-d3-nodes-after-transform/18561829).

While getBBox() works for an untransformed space, if scale and translation have been applied to the layout then it will no longer be accurate. The getBoundingClientRect() function has worked well for me in a force layout project when pan and zoom are in effect, where I wanted to attach HTML Div elements as labels to the nodes instead of using SVG Text elements.

Comment: Note that at least in Firefox 59 `element.getBoundingClientRect()` works with `transform="rotate(25)"` but not with `style="transform: rotate(25deg)"` e.g. css transformations.

Answer (score 11):

You can use the function **[`getBBox()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGraphicsElement/getBBox)** to get the bounding box for the path. This will give you the position and size of the tightest rectangle that could contain the rendered path.

An advantage of using this method over reading the `x` and `y` values is that it will work with all graphical objects. There are more objects than paths that do not have `x` and `y`, for example circles that have `cx` and `cy` instead.

Answer (score 5):

I use the consolidate function, like so:

```
 element.transform.baseVal.consolidate()
```

The .e and .f values correspond to the x and y coordinates

Comment: This apparently no longer works in Chrome. It returns `null` for me.

Answer (score 1):

i can handle it like that ;

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(zones)
    .enter()
    .append("rect")
    .attr("id", function (d) { return "zone" + d.zone; })
    .attr("class", "zone")
    .attr("x", function (d, i) {
        if (parseInt(i / (wcount)) % 2 == 0) {
            this.xcor = (i % wcount) * zoneW;
        }
        else {
            this.xcor = (zoneW * (wcount - 1)) - ((i % wcount) * zoneW);
        }

        return this.xcor;
    })
```

and anymore you can find x coordinate

```
svg.select("#zone1").on("click",function(){alert(this.xcor});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
svg.selectAll("rect")
.attr('x',function(d,i){
    // get x coord
    console.log(this.getBBox().x, 'or', d3.select(this).attr('x'))
})
.attr('y',function(d,i){
    // get y coord
    console.log(this.getBBox().y)
})
.attr('dx',function(d,i){
    // get dx coord
    console.log(parseInt(d3.select(this).attr('dx')))
})
```

Comment: Thanks, your reference to getBBox() is helpful, but some explanation would complete the answer

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to select an area of svg with a rectangle and get all the elements from it. For this, element.getBoundingClientRect() worked perfectly for me. It returns current coordinates of svg elements regardless of whether svg is scaled or transformed.

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that you draw `rect` inside `g` inside `svg`. You applied some transformations to `g`. And you want to get local x,y `rect` coordinates when you move mouse over `rect`.
Example in TypeScript

```js
rectD3Selection.on('mousemove', (event: MouseEvent) => {
  const clientBox = (event.currentTarget as SVGRectElement).getBBox();
  const clientRect = (event.currentTarget as SVGRectElement).getBoundingClientRect();
  const localX = Math.round(((event.clientX - clientRect.x) / clientRect.width) * clientBox.width);
  const localY = Math.round(((event.clientY - clientRect.y) / clientRect.height) * clientBox.height);
});
```