# Get the center where most of points are concentrated on 2D chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a `2D` chart where points form clusters. I need a way of setting labels to these clusters, so I need the coordinates of where the majority of points of the cluster concentrate. Unfortunately I can not use `getBoundingBoxCenter` because there are points that lie outside of the main cluster. Here is what I have right now:

```
    createClusterLabels = () => {
        if (this.props.mainData && this.props.mainData.length || this.props.type === "main") {
            var numClust = this.props.type === "marker" ? this.props.mainData.length : this.props.datum.length;
            var that = this;
            var groups = d3.select("svg > .nv-scatterChart").selectAll(".nv-groups > .nv-group");
           groups.each(function(data, idx) {
             let key = data["key"];
             let g = d3.select(this);
             let parent = d3.select(this.parentNode);
             let center = that.getBoundingBoxCenter(g);
             let margin = key.length === 1 ? 3 : 7;
             let old_key = parent.selectAll("text")
                              .filter(function(textData) {
                                let text = d3.select(this).text();
                                  if (text === key) {
                                    return true;
                                  }
                                  return false;
                              });
            // If we are adding the nodes the first time, they should be 'nulls' in current html
            let size = old_key.size();
            if (size === 0 && key <= numClust) {
                    parent.append("circle")
                         .attr("cx", center[0])
                         .attr("cy", center[1])
                         .attr("r", 10)
                         .attr('fill-opacity', 0)
                         .style("stroke", "black");
                    parent.append("text")
                          .attr("x", center[0] - margin)
                          .attr("y", center[1])
                          .attr("dy", ".35em")
                          .style("font-weight", "bold")
                          .style("fill", "black")
                          .text(key);
                }
            });
          }

  }
```

The `center` is now imprecise. The chart looks the following way:

[image]

I need a way of excluding certain points that lie outside the main concentration of them. Is it possible to achieve in javascript?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to determine the position of each single point inside each cluster, then exclude the points that are 1 standard deviation above on `x` or `y`, and then with the remaining points, just use average. Here is what I did:

```
...
groups.each(function(data, idx) {
         let key = data["key"];
         let g = d3.select(this);
         let parent = d3.select(this.parentNode);
         //let center = that.getBoundingBoxCenter(g);
         let children = g[0][0].childNodes;
         let allPoints = [...Array(children.length)].map((child, idx) => {
            return d3.transform(d3.select(children[idx]).attr("transform")).translate;
         })
         let center = that.getAveragePoint(allPoints);
 ...
```

Where `getAveragePoint()` is:

```
  getAveragePoint = (vals) => {
    let arrX = vals.map(arr => { return arr[0]; });
    let arrY = vals.map(arr => { return arr[1]; });
    let avgX = avg(arrX);
    let avgY = avg(arrY);
    let stDevX = stDev(arrX);
    let stDevY = stDev(arrY);
    let newArrX = arrX.filter(x => {
      if (Math.abs(x - avgX) < stDevX) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    let newArrY = arrY.filter(y => {
      if (Math.abs(y - avgY) < stDevY) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    });
    let newAvgX = avg(arrX);
    let newAvgY = avg(arrY);

    return [newAvgX,newAvgY];
  }
```

`stDev` and `avg` are just functions for finding standard deviation and average in the supplied arrays. Really helpful turned out the following thread:

[How to get coordinates of an svg element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19154631/how-to-get-coordinates-of-an-svg-element)

For the most important line to figure out: `return d3.transform(d3.select(children[idx]).attr("transform")).translate`

Resulting chart:

[image]