# Positioning SVG elements via .getBoundingClientRect() in variable-width div

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a bit of an annoying problem.

I'm trying to position a bunch of SVG circle elements according to an existing bunch of SVG text elements that share similar properties.

The circle elements are created in a very separate process than the text elements, so positioning the new elements just using the same transforms etc. as the old one isn't a viable option.

I'm trying to use .getBoundingClientRect() to get the positions since the text elements are transformed into position (so .getBBox() isn't an option) rather than positioned by x and y attributes.

With .getBoundingClientRect(), I can get the correct size/arrangement of the new elements, but since the width of the svg-containing div is variable, there's always a bit of a weird offset that I can't quite account for.

I created a simplified example of my issue [here](https://jsfiddle.net/rrpfmm6d/). Resize and refresh the page to see the issue in action.

The code I use to position the circle elements is replicated below.

```
var circs = theSvg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(theCircles)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 15)
    .attr("fill", "#f00")
    .style("opacity", 0.3)
    .attr("transform", function(d){

      var sizeDif = 800/(d3.select(".svgTestHolder")[0][0].getBoundingClientRect()["width"]);

      var theNum = parseInt(d.split("&")[1]);
      var thePosition = theSvg.selectAll("text").filter(function(e){
      return e == theNum;})[0];
      var theCoords = thePosition[0].getBoundingClientRect();

      var leftOffset = d3.select(".svgTestHolder")[0][0].getBoundingClientRect()["left"];
      var leftOffset2 = d3.select(".svgTest")[0][0].getBoundingClientRect()["left"];
      var bottomOffset = d3.select(".svgTestHolder")[0][0].getBoundingClientRect()["top"];
      var bottomOffset2 = d3.select(".svgTest")[0][0].getBoundingClientRect()["top"];

      return
      "translate(" + ((theCoords["left"] - leftOffset - leftOffset2)  
       * sizeDif) + "," + ((theCoords["top"] - bottomOffset - bottomOffset2) 
       * sizeDif) + ")";
 })
```

EDIT:

This is a very delayed update just to note that while I was unable to answer my question as stated, I was able to make a workable solution based on Paul LeBeau's suggestion to extract the transforms from the target element.

In my case, I had to use a series of consecutive transforms rather than a combination of transforming and changing the x/y position (due to certain realities of the project not represented in the linked example). But I'm happy to have found an answer!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your example works fine for me on Chrome. But really that's only because the SVG is the only thing on the page.  If I add some text above the SVG everything goes wrong.

https://jsfiddle.net/rrpfmm6d/1/

Is this the problem you are talking about?

If so, the reason is because you are making the wrong choice in using `getBoundingClientRect()`.  It provides coordinates in screen space. It's origin is the top left of the window (or iframe in the case of jsfiddle).

You should be using `getBBox()`. The values it returns are in the same coordinate space as the SVG elements.  It's origin is (normally) at the top left of the SVG.

In summary, use the coordinates returned by calling `getBBox()` on your `<text>` element to calculate the position for your circle.  If the circles are inserted into the same SVG as the text, there will be no need to do any adjusting with the div or svg offsets.

Comment: I realize that theoretically getBBox() would solve my problem, but since I used transform on the items I want the position of, getBBox() isn't a solution. That's why I've been trying to position by offsetting according to getBoundingClientRect() and adding/subtracting the offset of parent elements as needed (see [updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrpfmm6d/3/)). I've been looking for alternatives to getBBox() for transformed elements, including applying the SVG transform matrix to the text elements' x and y (as per [this guy's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18561829/3899852) solution).

Comment: You say you can't use the same transforms, but why can you not just copy them from the text elements?  Like this: https://jsfiddle.net/rrpfmm6d/5/

Comment: I've played a bit with extracting the transform, but haven't done it quite as you said because I'm trying to avoid setting cx and cy positions on the circles since (in the actual piece) I'm already transforming the circles according to another set of parameters and so am trying to keep the cx and cy at 0. I'll give your suggestion a spin as well as look at applying multiple transformations and report back. Thanks!