# getBoundingClientRect of SVG Path not working

Tags: javascript, nodelist, getboundingclientrect

I am making a library for Google Geo Charts on click zooming (API != zoom)

I need to get the width or height of the svg paths so I can filter them and store their coordinates in an array object. I was able to store alaska and hawaii g elements coords but with the continental US I have to go one level deeper to path and am having a hard time realizing where I am going wrong.

I am getting undefined on the continental nodeList.

```
google.visualization.events.addOneTimeListener(chart, 'ready', function (e){
            google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function (e){

              var selection = chart.getSelection(),
                  selectedState = '',
                  nodes = document.querySelectorAll("g[clip-path]")[0].childNodes[0],
                  continental = nodes.childNodes[0],
                  alaska = nodes.childNodes[1],
                  hawaii = nodes.childNodes[2],
                  stateCoords = {},
                  nl = null,
                  zoomX = null,
                  zoomY = null;

              //////////////////////////////
              //Get Coordinates of States//
              /////////////////////////////

              getCoords(alaska);
              getCoords(hawaii);
              // getCoords(continental);
              console.log(stateCoords);

              function getCoords(nodeList){

                function getZoom(nodeList, s){
                  nl = nodeList.getBoundingClientRect();
                  zoomY = nl.top + (nl.height/2);
                  zoomX = nl.left + (nl.width/2);
                  stateCoords[s] = [zoomX, zoomY];
                }

                if (nodeList == alaska) {
                    getZoom(nodeList, 1);
                } 
                else if (nodeList == hawaii){
                    getZoom(nodeList, 11);
                } 
                else {
                    console.log('continental');
                    var nodeListLength = nodeList.childNodes.length,
                        i = 0,
                        s = 0;

                    for (i; i < nodeListLength; i++) {
                      console.log(nodeList.childNodes[i]);
                      var pathBound = nodeList.childNodes[i].getBoundingClientRect();

                      if (pathBound.height > 3 && s != 1 && s!= 11) {
                          getZoom(nodeList[i], s);
                          s++;
                      } else { s++; }
                    }

                  }
              }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Positioning SVG elements via .getBoundingClientRect() in variable-width div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158656/positioning-svg-elements-via-getboundingclientrect-in-variable-width-div)

Comment: Without the SVG data or a jsFiddle, and without any details of the error or of what you get (and what you expect), it's quite difficult to debug things, but I would expect `getZoom(nodeList[i]);` should be `getZoom(nodeList.childNodes[i]);`. Also, you have a weird use of functions and variable scope.

Comment: Thanks for the input. How should one be using functions and variable scope?