# Scaling SVG country map relative to the selected district center

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, svg

I have an svg country map and I'm trying to achieve the effect when you click on a district and then see an animated scaling relative to selected district, i.e. scaling with `transform-origin` point in the center of a clicked district. And I would prefer **not to use any libraries**.

1. First of all, why [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/smorkiri/bo73g53y/), when we have `svg` `viewBox` attribute setted, `polygon`s drawn with `getBoundingClientRect()` points don't match their actual elements `svg`, `map`, `e.target`?
2. If we add some coefficients like [**here**](https://jsfiddle.net/smorkiri/6hya23p8/), then what `viewBoxMapCoefX1` and `viewBoxMapCoefX1` we need so the `mapPolygon` drawn with `getBoundingClientRect()` points matches actual `map` element?
3. When I try to scale `map` by adding:

   ```
   // ANIMATION HERE
   map.style.transformOrigin = transformOriginX + "px " + transformOriginY + "px";
   map.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
   ```

   it looks like `transformOrigin` value is wrong. If I try to change `viewBox` value by adding:

   ```
   // ANIMATION HERE
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.x = bounding.left;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.y = bounding.top;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.width = bounding.width;
   svg.viewBox.baseVal.height = bounding.height;
   ```

   then how can I make scaling animation with CSS (**no SMIL**)?

Any help or advice on this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30158656/positioning-svg-elements-via-getboundingclientrect-in-variable-width-div

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [@OwenAyres's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36578597/4989968) 1 part of question has been solved.

Instead of scaling `map` straight relative to the selected district center we can find district's center in `%` insted of `px` and then move district's center to `map`'s center and then make scale:

```
// ANIMATION HERE
var transformOriginXPercent = (50 - transformOriginX * 100 / mapBounding.width) * scale;
var transformOriginYPercent = (50 - transformOriginY * 100 / mapBounding.height) * scale;
var scaleText = "scale(" + scale + ")";
var translateText = "translate(" + transformOriginXPercent + "%," + transformOriginYPercent + "%)";

map.style.transformOrigin = "50% 50%";
map.style.transform = translateText + " " + scaleText;
```

and get [expected result](https://jsfiddle.net/smorkiri/35qycv6x/).

But there is still a question what coefficients for `transformOriginX` and `transformOriginY` are correct to get the result in the following form:

```
map.style.transformOrigin = (transformOriginX) + "px " + (transformOriginY) + "px";
map.style.transform = "scale(" + scale + ")";
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You should be using `.getBBox()` instead of `BoundingClientRect` to get the coordinates, as this will be based on the SVG itself and not the screen.

3) You are applying the transforms to the group tag, whereas it makes sense for these to be applied to the SVG element itself instead. You may have tried this already, but the transform origin value will all be based on the co-ordinates you're getting previously? So long as the animation works as intended, there is no issue with the animation front from what I can see.

```
// ANIMATION HERE
var svg = document.querySelector("svg");
svg.style.transformOrigin = '50% 50%';
svg.style.transform = 'scale(4)';
```

Comment: 1. `.getBBox()` did the trick, thank you! Is there any caniuse information about this method?

Comment: 3. I'm afraid I'm not clearly understand you. I've updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smorkiri/s6f3arot/) with `.getBBox()` and made scaling with `svg.style.*`, but I still have scalling issues for small districts at left.

Comment: @smorkiri why are you dynamically calculating the scale based on the district? Do you want different levels of zoom for different districts?