# How to determine if D3 tree node falls outside SVG container

Tags: d3.js, svg, tree, position

I'm using this implementation of a D3 tree layout:

http://bl.ocks.org/robschmuecker/7880033

I've got my tree responding to outside events, and for that, I'd like to know if a certain node is currently invisible (outside of svg container), so that I could for example recenter it.

After some research I found this SO answer which looked exactly what I needed:

[Getting Screen Positions of D3 Nodes After Transform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18554224/getting-screen-positions-of-d3-nodes-after-transform)

When dragging a node in the upper left corner and clicking on it, I would expect the coordinates to be [0,0].
But for some reason the x coordinate is always wrong by a pretty large offset.
Made a fiddle about it here:

https://jsfiddle.net/syberyan/yd8L4v0q/

I modified the click() function so that it prints the coordinates of the target node.

```
function getElementCoords(element, coords) {
    var ctm = element.getCTM(),
    x = ctm.e + coords.x*ctm.a + coords.y*ctm.c,
    y = ctm.f + coords.x*ctm.b + coords.y*ctm.d;
    return {x: x, y: y};
};

function click(d) {
    if (d3.event.defaultPrevented) return; // click suppressed
    d3.selectAll('.node').each(function (node, i) {
    if (d === node) {
      let coords = getElementCoords(this, node);
      console.log(coords.x, coords.y); // shows coords relative to my svg container
    }
  });
}
```

I'm a D3 newbie so I probably did something wrong, but what? Or maybe there's a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't look too closely at the linked question or your current calculations.  Instead, I think the calculations can be simplified to:

```
function getElementCoords(element) {      
  // translate on node
  var trans = d3.transform(d3.select(element).attr('transform')).translate,
      // transform on parent "zoom" container
      transFormParent = d3.transform(d3.select(element.parentNode).attr('transform')),
      // translate on zoom container
      transParent = transFormParent.translate,
      // scale on zoom container
      scaleParent = transFormParent.scale,
      // final position of node
      pos = {
        x: trans[0] + transParent[0]/scaleParent[0],
        y: trans[1] + transParent[1]/scaleParent[1]
      };

    return pos;
}
```

Call it as:

```
function click(d) {
  console.log(getElementCoords(this));
}
```

Updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yd8L4v0q/9/).

**EDITS**

@Christian pointed out in the comments, my math was off, should have been:

```
function getElementCoords(element) {      
  // translate on node
  var trans = d3.transform(d3.select(element).attr('transform')).translate,
      // transform on parent "zoom" container
      transFormParent = d3.transform(d3.select(element.parentNode).attr('transform')),
      // translate on zoom container
      transParent = transFormParent.translate,
      // scale on zoom container
      scaleParent = transFormParent.scale,
      // final position of node
      pos = {
        x: trans[0] * scaleParent[0] + transParent[0], 
        y: trans[1] * scaleParent[1] + transParent[1]
      };

    return pos;
}
```

Comment: Seems to work, but not after zooming. Coordinates get way too large, must be an issue with the scale calculation.

Comment: This seems to do the job:
`coords = {
        x: trans[0] * scaleParent[0] + transParent[0],
        y: trans[1] * scaleParent[1] + transParent[1]
      };`

Comment: @Christian, oops, my bad.  Thanks for catching that.  I've updated my answer with your corrected math for posterity's sake.